# How to restart a systemd service on-sucess and on-failure into a single service?

Tags: systemd

I want to restart a process in on-sucess and on-failure in a the same process, example:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/home/user/test
KillMode=process
Restart=on-success on-failure
RestartPreventExitStatus=255
Type=simple
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use `Restart=always`. See the [documentation in systemd.service(5).](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=)